# ng server rebuild all instead of detect unchanged chunks

Tags: angular-cli

When I do an ng serve, it builds without errors, but when I do a small change in a CSS or HTML, it rebuild the entire app with all node_modules. I remember that few weeks ago this didn't happen.

It's annoying because now when I'm developing, any change delays 1 minute or more recompiling.

Maybe is a missconfiguration in the config files so I paste here:

`package.json` (XX.XX.XX.XX is my server IP)

```
{
  "name": "miac",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "gesti": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration gestiobra --aot --source-map=false --host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --port 4200 --vendorChunk=true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "version": "^0.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "terser": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.1",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "miac": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "go",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            },
            "miac": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment_0.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/favicon.ico",
                  "with": "src/assets/favicon_0.ico"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "miac:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "miac": {
              "browserTarget": "miac:build:miac"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "miac:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "miac:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "miac-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "miac:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "miac"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the error.

```
"vendorChunk": false
```

Must be true to avoid a complete rebuild.